# The Sufficient Conditions to have Cluster Points in Arbitrary Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Although I already know the answer to the following question is somehow obvious, I would like to make sure since I am a little bit confused.

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a topological space and $\mathbb{E} \subset \mathbb{X}$ a (non-empty) subset.

What are sufficient condition assumed on $\mathbb{E}$ to make sure that it has, at least, one cluster point?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: What is your **definition** of a cluster point of a set $E$?

Comment: A **limit point** $p$ of $E$ has the property that every open neighbourhood of $p$ intersects $E$ in a point different from $p$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes

Comment: Then a finite set can only have a limit point in a space that is not $T_1$ etc.

Comment: $E$ infinite and $X$ limit point compact is a trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

If we know nothing else about $X$ than it is a topological space, there are no simple conditions for $E \subset X$ to have a cluster point. For example it might be that $X$ is a discrete space (all sets are open) and in that case no subset has a cluster point.

If we are asking about special types of $X$ then a familiar condition is $X$ being compact. In this case any infinite $E$ has a cluster point. If moreover $X$ is compact and Hausdorff then $E$ being infinite is equivalent to it having a cluster point.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is finite $T_0$, there always is a non-empty subset without a limit point.

So $X$ must be infinite or not $T_0$.

If $X$ is $T_1$, no finite subset has a limit point, so your only hope for a sufficient condition is to restrict to **infinite** $E$ and then the property is equivalent to limit point compactness, or countable compactness.

The rest is unclear to me at the present. An indiscrete space of any size $2$ or more always has this property, e.g.